# How can I know when Facebook access token will expire?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Facebook API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={uri}&scope={scope}
```

When I go there, I get an access token which is something like

```
access_token=CAAEfRaZBOb0sBAP...(abbreviated)...0obQeBDWvPUxUfJ6&expires_in=6207
```

In here, what does `expires_in=6207` mean? Can I know exact expiring time from this?

Answer (score 0):

Those are probably seconds, since a default User Token is valid for 2 hours.

But it is not a good idea to use that value, better refresh the token with FB.getLoginStatus whenever the user visits your website/app, and use error handling (try/catch) to avoid problems with an invalid token.